# Display flex shrinks div item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following CSS for my display flex:

```
.well-contact{
    background-color:rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.5);
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px #f5f5f5;
}
#contact{
    background: url(../img/sketch.jpg) center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 110vh;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
textarea{
    resize: none;
}
```

And this is my markup:

```
<section class="first-block" id="contact">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1 class="text-center">Contáctame</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-centered">
                        <div class="well well-lg well-contact">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="uname" class="control-label">Nombre</label>
                                <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="nombre">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="uemail" class="control-label">Correo</label>
                                <input type="email" name="uemail" id="uemail" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="correo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="umessage" class="control-label">Correo</label>
                                <textarea name="umessage" id="umessage" class="form-control input-lg" rows="6" placeholder="mensaje"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

For some reason, when I do `display:flex;` the following happens:

[image]

Is there a way `display:flex;` doesn't shrink the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give `flex: 1;` to the `.container-fluid` element so that it would grow to fill the available space within the flex container.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/vavid/1/edit)**

Also consider using a custom class name in order to avoid altering the twitter bootstrap's default fluid container:

```
<div class="container-fluid flex-item"> ... </div>
```

```css
.flex-item { flex: 1; }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work. I'm still new to flex and working with it is being a challenge. Mainly because I'm the guy that learned to make websites by using tables.

Comment: @hsoto Don't mention it. You might want to take a look at this article by [Chris Coyier on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for further info.